# Set frontmatter from global data 11ty

Tags: eleventy

I want to create static blog with a 11ty, using wordpress api. I fetch posts (file `_data/posts.js`):

```
const EleventyFetch = require("@11ty/eleventy-fetch");

module.exports = async function() {
  const url = "http://www.some-url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100";
  const maxPages = 100;
  let page = 1;

  let responses = [];

  while (page <= maxPages) {
    const urlWithPage = `${url}&page=${page}`
    try {
      data = await EleventyFetch(urlWithPage, {
        duration: "1d",
        type: "json"
      })
    } catch(e) {
      break
    }

    responses.push(data);

    page++
  }

  responses = responses.flat(2);
  return responses;
};
```

and there in each of them is an array of tags related to those posts. For example, tags for first post:

```
tags: [ 'my_tag' ]
```

And I have file, for rendering all of posts with this frontmatter:

```
---
layout: layouts/post.njk
title: Index
description: Starter pack for site.
pagination:
  data: readyPosts
  size: 1
  alias: tag
tags: tag.tags
permalink: "/{{ tag.slug | slug }}/"
---

{{ tags | log }}
```

When I am trying to set tags from post data, and log it,`tag.tags` is interpreted as a string.

```
[ 'posts', 'tag.tags' ]
```

I need the result to be like:

```
[ 'posts', 'my_tag' ]
```

How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eleventyComputed`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/) to set your `tags` key based on your pagination object.

Using a [template Javascript data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-template-dir/) we can set tags using a Javascript function. You'll need to name these files according to your file structure. Reference the documentation for more information.

Assuming your template is called `posts.njk`, create a `posts.11tydata.js` file right next to it.

```js
// posts.11tydata.js
module.exports = {
  eleventyComputed: {
    tags: (data) => {
      return data.tags.slice().concat(data.tag.tags.slice())
    },
  },
}
```

This will combine any tags set in your front matter with tags from your data. If you want all the posts to have the "posts" tag, set it in your template.

In `posts.njk` (or whatever filename):

```yaml
---
# ...
pagination:
  data: readyPosts
  size: 1
  alias: tag
tags: ["posts"]
permalink: "/{{ tag.slug | slug }}/"
# ...
---
```

Please be aware that this method **will not actually add your tags/pages to the `collections` object**. This is due to a restriction in Eleventy (see the first note [on this page](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/)). However, accessing the `tags` key in your template will work exactly as expected. If you do need collections, you can add them yourself using the [collections API](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#collection-api-methods).